# Cloud function that invokes Vision API

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to Google Cloud Functions and node.js. I think this is actually not very difficult, but I'm literally trying to code this for more than 17 hours already...

I need a Google Cloud function that uses Vision API Safe Search and returns the results. I want to invoke this function on an android app and receive the results also in that android app.

I've found this almost complete implementation in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/samples/vision-safe-search-detection-gcs):

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client libraries
const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');

// Creates a client
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
 */
// const bucketName = 'Bucket where the file resides, e.g. my-bucket';
// const fileName = 'Path to file within bucket, e.g. path/to/image.png';

// Performs safe search property detection on the remote file
const [result] = await client.safeSearchDetection(
  `gs://${bucketName}/${fileName}`
);
const detections = result.safeSearchAnnotation;
console.log(`Adult: ${detections.adult}`);
console.log(`Spoof: ${detections.spoof}`);
console.log(`Medical: ${detections.medical}`);
console.log(`Violence: ${detections.violence}`);
```

I have the full path `gs://${bucketName}/${fileName}` ready to pass in as a function parameter. So we could even simplify the above code and leave out the bucketName and fileName variables and just have one single variable `filePath`. And that variable is a function argument.

However, as said, I'm already spending 17+ hours on this and I always get some errors, like for example `detections` is `null` for some reason, or the function argument `filePath` I pass is not read at all (instead it is invalid...) or it only works from the Cloud Console and not from the app itself, or my returning value is invalid etc.

No matter what I try, I just can't get it working...

Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting when you run the code?  Where is the code running?  Is it in Cloud Functions, Cloud Run, GKE, a Compute Engine or somewhere else?   I'd be tempted to suggest running in Cloud Shell or a Compute Engine just to validate that it works as you expect.

Comment: @Lukas Niessen Did you had a chance to check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71226257/13171940)?

Answer (score 1):

In order to have a Cloud Function that invokes Cloud Vision API, you could follow [this guide](https://medium.com/swlh/exploring-cloud-vision-landmark-api-with-firebase-cloud-functions-7b05a21e6c46), which is a walkthrough to get started *Exploring Cloud Vision Landmark API With Firebase Cloud Functions*.

- First, you'll find the section ***[Setting up Firebase with Cloud storage and Cloud Functions](https://medium.com/swlh/exploring-cloud-vision-landmark-api-with-firebase-cloud-functions-7b05a21e6c46#:%7E:text=Setting%20up%20Firebase%20with%20Cloud%20storage%20and%20Cloud%20Functions)*** which tells how to set up a Firebase project and install the Firebase tools for Node.js on your machine, also to login the CLI.
- Then, you have to ***[Create project folder](https://medium.com/swlh/exploring-cloud-vision-landmark-api-with-firebase-cloud-functions-7b05a21e6c46#:%7E:text=Create%20project%20folder)***
- After that, ***[Setting up Google Cloud Vision API](https://medium.com/swlh/exploring-cloud-vision-landmark-api-with-firebase-cloud-functions-7b05a21e6c46#:%7E:text=folder%20for%20you.-,Setting%20up%20Google%20Cloud%20Vision%20API,-To%20set%20up)*** is an important step in order to have the Cloud Vision API configured and working. I strongly recommend double-checking that you have *Linked a billing account* to avoid issues related to this, and have a straight troubleshooting when testing your code and use a *Service account* instead of your individual account as stated in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts#background).
- The next step is [Coding the Cloud Function](https://medium.com/swlh/exploring-cloud-vision-landmark-api-with-firebase-cloud-functions-7b05a21e6c46#:%7E:text=Coding%20the%20Cloud%20Function). As the example used in the article is to detect landmarks and you want to use the Safe Search Detection, instead of using the code provided in the article, you can use the following one:

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import vision from "@google-cloud/vision";

export const safeSearchDetection = functions.https.onRequest(
    async (req: functions.https.Request, res: functions.Response<any>) => {
        const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
        try {
            // Bucket where the file resides, e.g. my-bucket
            const bucketName = "my-bucket";
            
            // Name of the file within bucket, sent inside the body request 
            const fileName = `${req.body.photoId}`;
            const [result] = await client.safeSearchDetection(
                `gs://${bucketName}/${fileName}`
            );

            const detections = result.safeSearchAnnotation || {};

            console.log(`Adult: ${detections.adult}`);
            console.log(`Spoof: ${detections.spoof}`);
            console.log(`Medical: ${detections.medical}`);
            console.log(`Violence: ${detections.violence}`);

            res.send(detections);
            res.end();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            res.send(error);
        }
    }
);
```

Remember to replace `bucketName` with your actual bucket name. The variable `projectId` mentioned in the article is no longer needed. After you've saved your code, you can [compile the code](https://medium.com/swlh/exploring-cloud-vision-landmark-api-with-firebase-cloud-functions-7b05a21e6c46#:%7E:text=sure%20that%20you-,compile%20the%20code,-.%20While%20still%20in) with the command `npm run build`.

- Finally, the section ***[Testing the Cloud Function](https://medium.com/swlh/exploring-cloud-vision-landmark-api-with-firebase-cloud-functions-7b05a21e6c46#:%7E:text=Testing%20the%20Cloud%20Function)*** tells how to *start a test server* to run your function.

  > Make sure that you have your service account JSON file set as an environmental variable; otherwise, it won’t work!

You can upload the following [image](https://github.com/henryn/imageanalyzer/blob/d71dc11a2bdbe477f32fb27239a3e055e1a09317/zombie-949916_1280.jpg) to your bucket to test the function.

After creating a POST request in Postman as pointed out in [the article](https://medium.com/swlh/exploring-cloud-vision-landmark-api-with-firebase-cloud-functions-7b05a21e6c46#:%7E:text=create%20a%20new%20POST%20request), you will have a response like this:

```json
{
    "adult":"VERY_UNLIKELY",
    "spoof":"VERY_UNLIKELY",
    "medical":"POSSIBLE",
    "violence":"VERY_LIKELY",
    "racy":"UNLIKELY",
    "adultConfidence":0,
    "spoofConfidence":0,
    "medicalConfidence":0,
    "violenceConfidence":0,
    "racyConfidence":0,
    "nsfwConfidence":0
}
```

> If everything is working, you are now ready to deploy the function with
>  `firebase deploy --only functions`
>
> Once you see *Deploy complete!*, open Postman and replace the request URL with the *Function URL* output by Firebase deploy. You can also find it in the Firebase console by clicking *Functions* in the side menu.
> ...
> It should give the same response as before, but this time from the Firebase server instead of your local machine.

See also:

- [Google Cloud Functions Analyze Image Example](https://github.com/henryn/imageanalyzer#google-cloud-functions-analyze-image-example). *This sample shows you how to analyze an image for inappropriate content in a Storage-triggered Cloud Function.*
- [Google Cloud Function calling Vision API](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lTh6lZsEBU). [Video]. YouTube.